# Dispatching click event on anchor in timeout stops following link after 1000 ms

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, settimeout, dispatchevent

Here is the plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/zhWBY7G0ALnM8dBSZ5nm?p=preview

If you change that `1001` to `1000`, the dispatch will work as expected - the link will be followed. The event handler always gets invoked as expected. It's just the default behavior (following the link) stops working. I googled around for a reason to no avail.

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
  trigger.addEventListener('click', clickLink);

  var element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // this will work regardless...
    console.log('link clicked!')
  });

  function clickLink(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
      element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }, 1001);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
<span id="trigger">Click Me</span>
```

This is a simplified version of an angular example in which i try to implement a timeout before following a link in a directive. Same issue.
https://plnkr.co/edit/yGBp6PkvpbQkQUTeHX40?p=preview

What is happening? Why the magical 1000 ms cutoff? I'm on chrome.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code in the question

Comment: It is working for me even with 2000

Comment: On firefox, I get a warning "FF prevented this site from opening a popup window" with a TO of 1001. 1000ms works fine.  So it must be a security feature...

Comment: There are features which block opening window from non user initiated method invocation... may be the 1s is a limit imposed by the browser implementation